# How to detect a human behind the glass?

Tags: sensor, image-sensor

I am challenged with a task of detecting a human *from behind the glass*. Could you please suggest what kind of sensor will be a good fit for the job?

A sensor can only be mounted *on the inside* of the glass panel approximately 1 meter above the head or at the knee level.

How do I detect if there is anyone standing in the immediate proximity from the glass panel on the other side?

[image]

Comment: Instead of dumping your challenge to let others do your challenge, have you already some ideas to solve this?

Comment: "Obviously" a camera and something running OpenCV (or SimpleCV) in some form or another.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a camera.

Comment: This is a valid, on-topic question, so what's the rationale for wanting to close it?

Comment: The most obvious answer (PIR sensor) won't work since most glass and IR-transparent plastic is opaque to far IR (10um-ish). Second most obvious- camera and software- might work- what if the human is wearing a [Dalek](http://torontoist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/082513-FanExpoSelects-DROSTphoto-0067.jpg) (or bear) costume, for example?

Answer (score 0):

If the glass is IR transparent and the only moving thing on the other side of the glass is warm-blooded, you could use a passive infrared (PIR) motion detector.

If the glass isn't IR transparent (or even if it is) you could use an LDR configured to detect fast-ish changes in illumination from the other side of the glass.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by change in capacitance as the human gets close. Coat the inside of the window in conductive transparent "paint" and use a high frequency oscillator and look for a change in current taken by the "coating" as the human approaches. It's just a possibility to try out using a sheet of tin foil to see if it works.

If it works then a bear would also trigger a detect and because you live in Canada this may invalidate the idea.